# Can I have mixed data types in a tkinter Combobox?

Tags: tkinter, types, combobox

I'm trying to create a tkinter combobox with integers and strings as values. But it seems like whatever is selected from the combobox can only be assigned to either IntVar() or StringVar(). Is there a tkinter variable type that can take both integers and strings?

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(1000,1000))
integer = IntVar()
string = StringVar()
dropDownList = Combobox(root, value=[1,2,3,'x','y'], textvariable = integer) #what do I need to do with the textvariable?
dropDownList.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a tkinter variable type that can take both integers and strings?

No, there is not. However, the value from a `StringVar` can easily be converted to an integer if it's in the proper format.

Comment: This is what I thought, thanks.

Comment: How would you handle data type None? such that value = [None, 1,2,3,4,5]?

Comment: @Dan: you will have to use an empty string to represent `None`.